# Changing the image of the cell when it's checked

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

In my UITableView, i need to get the event of the user, so when the cell is selected(checked), i put `btn_checked.png` and when it's unchecked, i put the `btn_unchecked.png`.

I guess, what i try to do should be in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, so this is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray *listData =[self->tableContents objectForKey:

    [self->sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

    UITableViewCell* theCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"btn_unchecked.png"]];

    theCell.accessoryView = imageView;    
}
```

My snippet code doesn't work, so the `btw_unchecked.png` isn't placed when the row is checked, also, i need to get the event of checked/unchecked to place the right image to the right event.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, this code snippet will toggle the cell's checkmark when the cell is tapped. The pattern is to force a selective reload from the table's *datasource* when the *delegate* method is invoked.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Dequeue the cell... then:
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tvcOEList";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

i hope this will help you..